# Need Kafka consumer whch fetch data in batch

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have searched about Kafka batch consumer and I didn't find any valuable information.

**Use case :**

Producer will produce data very frequently and at consumer site we will consume data and from consumer & we will be posting data to Facebook and Google which have limits of data which can be posted.

Let me know if it is possible to pause consumer to consume data for specific time till other APIs consumes data from Consumer.

**Note :** This can be achieved by storm easily but I am not looking for this solution. We can also configure byte size in kafka but that won't serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple ways you could do this:

Option #1: Employ one consumer thread that handles all data consumption and hands off the messages to a blocking queue consumed by a worker thread pool. In dosing so could you easily scale the worker processes and consumers. But the offset commit management will be a little harder in this case.

Option #2: Simply invoke KafkaConsumer.pause() and KafkaConsumer.resume() methods to pause and resume fetching from specific partitions to implement your own logic.